# Internet connection is very slow

Tags: 12.04, internet-connection, mobile-broadband

I use GSM connection to surf Internet. Before I moved to Ubuntu I used windows 7 OS. It gave me good speed with GSM connection (100 KB/s). But now Ubuntu gives me a very slow speed (2-3 KB/s). So it is difficult to use GSM connection. In my country (Sri Lanka) mobile broadband services are very expensive so I cant move to another one. If I use GSM connection they give me free data (AirTel connection). For me that is the main reason to use GSM connection. Please, can anybody help me speed up my Internet?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The broadband companies specify on which distro their products are tested. For Ubuntu, this is mostly 9.10/10.04/10.10. Compatibility and speed are not yet tested on newer versions. Best you can do is use USB extension cable to get the dongle near to a window to increase signal as there might be some external interference.

In case of any doubts, please contact your regional customer care center for more information.

Comment: Any time. I have DOCOMO with similar problem.